# Drum beat mistake in Daydream by Wallace Collection?

Tags: recording

I noticed there is a off-beat drum at 0:50 in the song Daydream by Wallace Collection. At first I thought it's a sampling problem, but then every single version of this song I could find had this little peculiarity at 00:50...

Searching the internet I found no mention of this.

Have anyone noticed this? Is this in the original recording, or is there a version without it?

Comment: If the versions you listened to are the same as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9I_p8K6ZPg,  I suspect if there's no mention of it just because it's not *desperately* off, and it's not a particularly well-known song (at least in the Anglosphere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time [this song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daydream_%28Wallace_Collection_song%29) was released, bands still used live human drummers, and occasional imperfections in the beat were taken as a matter of course.  The era of drum machines and/or stitching together hundreds of runthroughs into a single perfect take didn't come until later.  Many of the signature recordings of the 60's and 70's were recorded under what would now be considered incredibly low-fi conditions.

Comment: I was hoping to find a properly recorded version but the only other one I found is a live one that also kinda lame (for me). Shame, it's a great song...

Comment: @traveh Maybe you'd prefer [the cover version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ua-HxucUWK8).

Comment: LOL how didn't I think of looking for a cover... I always look for cool covers! I like the version you posted, but I found [this one](https://www.youtube.com) that I like more.